# how to set UILabel text colour as a a background image

Tags: ios

i want to design a view in  which,`UILabel` text should remain transparent so that background image can see out through text i.e transparent text of `UILabel` 
with moving `UILabel` ,text colour should change according to background
 image 
please help me

```
UIImage *croppedImage=[self crop:self.demo.frame];

 self.demo.textColor=[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:croppedImage];
```

I'm cropping image with size of demo(UILabel ) and setting its text colour
but image gets double pixelate

Comment: [self crop:self.demo.frame] check this method, you are not getting the proper crop

Comment: can you u suggest me ,how to crop background imageView image with the size of UILabel size ?

Comment: you should have to analysis that what type of textcolor matches with image color , example if you have blackcolor image try to have darktextcolor of your uilabel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To Crop the Image by passing with the exact your LabelSize ;

```
// get sub image
- (UIImage*) getSubImageFrom: (UIImage*) img WithRect: (CGRect) rect {

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(rect.size);
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    // translated rectangle for drawing sub image
    CGRect drawRect = CGRectMake(-rect.origin.x, -rect.origin.y, img.size.width, img.size.height);

    // clip to the bounds of the image context
    // not strictly necessary as it will get clipped anyway?
    CGContextClipToRect(context, CGRectMake(0, 0, rect.size.width, rect.size.height));

    // draw image
    [img drawInRect:drawRect];

    // grab image
    UIImage* subImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return subImage;
}
```

Comment: dear its working ,but image gets double pixelate i.e image gets double

Comment: How come. Then check with your image. it should be of the same frame. put the imgView.ContentMode to aspectFit

Comment: is there any retina or non retina problem @Kumar KI

Comment: Yes, it might cause. how you are deal with the image

Comment: i have two view Square and rectangle view. and cropping image seen through any one of view. and set to finaleImageView wit aspect fit.